# Can I get a two-way transition speed with CSS for open and close?

Tags: css, transition

I have a full-screen overlay menu.

```
.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 70;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color:#415566;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 2.0s;
}

 <div id="menuActive"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</a></div>

 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
```

I have JS to call it to open and close:

```
     function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("navBar").style.height = "100%";
     }

     function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("navBar").style.height = "0%";
     }
```

Is it possible to have a different transition time for `openNav()` and `closeNav()`? At present, I am only able to control both.

Comment: You want to open and close after specified time period?

Comment: Instead of changing the element height, use JS to toggle elements class. Than for each class assign different transition time.

Comment: You managed to set a value for one CSS property in your JS code. Maybe you manage it for a second one as well …?

Comment: @AjayKumarOad I would like to be able to open it using 2.0 seconds and close it at 0.0 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an extra class to your `.overlay` to modify the transition:

```
 function openNav() {
    var navBar = document.getElementById("navBar");
    navBar.style.height = "100%";
    setTimeout(function(){
       navBar.classList.add("opened");
    }, 2000)
 }

 function closeNav() {
    var navBar = document.getElementById("navBar");
    navBar.style.height = "0%";
    setTimeout(function(){
       navBar.classList.remove("opened");
    }, 300)
 }
```

and the CSS for this class could be:

```
.opened {
    transition: height 300ms; /* The duration you want... */
}
```

> Also, take the good advice given by **skobaljic** in the question's comments about using JS to just add/remove classes for this kind of interaction.

Comment: Thanks. Great help!

Answer (score 0):

Here we go.

```
function openNav() {
 $("#navBar").show(1000);
}

function closeNav() {
 $("#navBar").hide();
}
```

Comment: So you want to animate during open?

Comment: Seems like OP is asking for different transition durations, not transition delays...